# Imageview doesn't displays when I set background color

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The structure of the XML file is :

```
FrameLayout 
    ImageView
    LinearLayout
        TextView
        TextView
```

When I'm using background color for the LinearLayout the ImageView's drawable doesn't appears. If I remove the bg color from the LinearLayout drawable is in it's place.

I'm adding the drawables in code like this :

```
              if( placetype == 0 )  {
                    ImageView im0 = (ImageView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.infowindow_imageview);
                    int imageResource0 = R.drawable.beer_white;
                    im0.setImageResource(imageResource0);
                } else if( placetype == 1 ) { 
                     //etc ...
```

And the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"    android:orientation="vertical"  >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?activatableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/map_info_top"  >     
          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/infowindow_imageview"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="top|right"
              android:layout_marginRight="-12dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              android:alpha="0.3"
              android:contentDescription="@null"
              android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/red_drink"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextHeader"
                        android:id="@+id/custom_infowindow_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"

                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"     />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextHeaderSub"
                        android:text="Click to Read more"                           
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                         />

            </LinearLayout>     

</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Since ImageView and LinearLayout are in a FrameLayout I didn't thought there will be a problem with overlapping Views.
Can someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LinearLayout is drawn over the ImageView. And since the background is not transparent, you can't see the Image. Try to put ImageView below LinearLayout in your XML resource

Comment: @mt0s because you are using FrameLayout.

Comment: @JaAd yeap my mistake :( `FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a **single** item.`

Comment: It's how FrameLayout works. It puts every child on top of all previous. Not below, as in simple LinearLayout. FrameLayout is like if you use RelativeLayout and forget to set params like android:below or set alignParentTop="true" for every child

Comment: Thank's a lot. It's been a while since I last used FrameLayout and I forgot it. Give me two more minutes to mark the answer as accepted.